# IE6 floating divs don't clear properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I'm trying to make a 2-column 'table' using floated elements:

```
<ul>
  <li class="odd">This will appear on the left</li>
  <li class="even">This will appear on the right</li>
  <li class="odd">This will appear on the left (2)</li>
  <li class="even">This will appear on the right (2)</li>
  <li class="odd">This will appear on the left (3)</li>
  <li class="even">This will appear on the right (3)</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { 
    margin: 20px 0px; 
    width: 880px;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 410px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

.odd { clear: left; }

.even {
    clear: right;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aeBex/)

This works great, but in IE6, the `even` elements don't clear, and end up stacked horizontally on the first row. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you remove `clear: left` and `clear: right`, your demo does not change in modern browsers, and it works in IE6. Is there some reason you need `clear`? One reason would be if your `li`s are not always going to be the same height as each other. Also, why are you supporting IE6? According to http://www.ie6countdown.com/ it has 1.4% of the market share in the UK.

Comment: @thirtydot Support is not my decision (Our products support NT4!). The elements are not the same height, and I think horizontal alignment is desired.

Comment: This approach works in IE6: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/SE2Mn/. What do you think?

Comment: unordered lists mimicking tables? surely there is a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about if you make the elements 50% width of the container, and float them all to the left, then each will float next to the last, until there are 2, then the next will appear on the next row.

```
ul { 
    width: 880px;
    overflow:hidden; /* to clear */
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This is going to get a bit nasty when I try and put in the margin for the right-hand elements

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. It's a slight adaptation of errkk's answer, so I'll mark his as accepted.

```
li { width: 48%; }

.odd { clear: both; }

.even { margin-left: 4%; }
```